# Get List of Classes from an object in java

Tags: java, class, reflection

Iam currently trying to create a distinct `List<Class> classList` which contains all Classes of an object for example

DemoObject.java

```
public class DemoObject {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private Boolean isActive;
    private List<NestedDemoObject> nested;
}
```

NestedDemoObject.java

```
public class NestedDemoObject {

    private Integer id;
    private String nameNest;
    private Boolean isActive;
}
```

What i want to create is a method `public List<Class> getDistinctClasses(Class cl);` which you give as input for example `DemoObject.class` and returns a list with

`[DemoObject.class, Integer.class, String.class, BigDecimal.class, Boolean.class, List.class, NestedDemoObject.class]`

Another example for `NestedDemoObject.class` would be

`[NestedDemoObject.class, Integer.class, String.class, Boolean.class]`

I tried to use the `.getDeclaredClasses()` from `Class` without any luck.
There is any way to get all nested classes from an object with Reflection API?

Any help or direction appreciated.

Comment: I believe what you're looking for are the classes of the `Fields`, correct?

Comment: yes correct, iam looking to get all distinct classes of the fields including the root object class (changed my examples post to include and the root object class)

Comment: @ohlec tryied Mark's solution with getDeclaredFields() and works great but as you said its impossible to get NestedDemoObject this way. there is any possible workaround for this ?

Comment: @ohlec Actually you're not right. The fields **DO KNOW** their own generic types. Please check my answer in a separate post.

Comment: @ETO indeed, thanks for that. I'll delete my comments to keep this concise.

Comment: @ETO …to some extend. The generic type of a field may depend on type variables of the declaring class (or even outer classes), resulting in an actual type which might not be reifiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution provided by Mark is partially correct. You're on the right way trying to retrieve the classes from declared fields. However `getType()` method does not reveal the generic types.

In order to access the generic types you should use `Field.getGenericType()` instead. It returns the classes as `Type` objects. The `Field` objects *DO KNOW* their own types (they are not erased as one may believe mistakenly).
This is a java 1.8+ example printing the types with generics:

```
Arrays.stream(DemoObject.class.getDeclaredFields())
            .map(Field::getGenericType)
            .map(Type::getTypeName)
            .distinct()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It will print the following result:

```
java.lang.Integer
java.lang.String
java.math.BigDecimal
java.lang.Boolean
java.util.List<com.eto.sandbox.NestedDemoObject>
```

If you want to play with generic types or parse them for any reason then you could use this example:

```
 Arrays.stream(DemoObject.class.getDeclaredFields())
            .map(Field::getGenericType)
            .distinct()
            .forEach(type -> {
                if (type instanceof Class) {
                    // This is a simple class
                } else if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                    // This is a generic type. You can parse its parameters recursively.
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer im going to test it. I think something like this could work

Comment: @PanosK, you're welcome! Feel free to ask questions if any.

Comment: BTW, take a look at `ParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()` method. It extracts generic sub-types.

Comment: Note that this information about generic types might be not present at runtime - but this is pretty much edge case, like some obfuscated code. As this information is just not required for JVM, so it can be stripped, but it is included by default. So in most cases solution like this is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this points you in the right direction:

```
for (Field f : DemoObject.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    System.out.println(f.getType().getName());
}
```

This prints:

```
java.lang.Integer
java.lang.String
java.math.BigDecimal
java.lang.Boolean
java.util.List
```

You can get a class instance through something like `Class.forName`.

I find it odd that `getDeclaredClasses` is not working for me either, and I will look into that. I'll update the answer when I know more.

**UPDATE**

`getDeclaredClasses` prints classes defined inside a class like so:

```
class DemoObject {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private Boolean isActive;
    private List<NestedDemoObject> nested;

    public class InnerClass {

    }
}
```

Then executing `getDeclaredClasses`:

```
for (Class<?> f : DemoObject.class.getDeclaredClasses()) {
    System.out.println(f.getName());
}
```

prints the value:

```
DemoObject$InnerClass
```

Comment: @PanosK I have updated my answer, figured out how `getDeclaredClasses` actually works.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for the help , so i have to go with getDeclaredFields() and somehow get the type of NestedDemoObject declared on List